# multi-tenant Lucene Server

Tags: solr, lucene

We are building a searching server. Users' data are stored in different locations, such as a third-party cloud or local disk. We provide searching function for them. We wonder whether it is possible to use Lucene in this project. We want to let users to build index locally and submit it to our server.

I planned to use Solr. But if then, user may need to submit the data to Solr server and let the server build the index. Our idea is to let the user submit the index. Is that possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Actually, it looks weird. Why you want users to index some data by themself?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are two reasons. First, the data could be large, we do not want them to upload it. Second, the data is encrypted. The client has a viewer app to view it. Now we want to use the viewer app to generate index. If we upload the data for indexing, it may compromise the privacy. Although the index would still leak some information, it is considered acceptable

Comment: As far as I understand - you want to client side t oenerate index data and send it to Solr?

I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Yes. I just try to find whether it is possible. The server is not necessary to be Solr. We may implement our new server based on Lucene. Then I want to merge index file from different users in the server side.

Comment: I see, interesting idea, actually. Nevert heard is it possilbe, or not.

Comment: Shall the clients be allowed to see each others indexed content or are there any security constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could merge different indexes in Solr/Lucene
Take a look here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MergingSolrIndexes or here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes

Hope it will helps.